# Implement progress bar in fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-progressbar

I have a activity contains  multiple fragments. Each fragment calls multiple http (Volley )request.How do i implement Progress Bar with this?

Answer (score 0):

Define a different progress bar in each fragment' layout , initilize them in each fragment. set visibility to gone. Whenever you start the volley request , set progress bars visibility to visible , and make it invisible again on volley response&error. This should work right?  I hope I understood you .

Comment: Ain't we writing boilerplate codes !.. Rather think about an approach .. 1 progress bar and common implementation having scope included in each fragment you instantiate... So you will be just enabling and disabling the progress bar without much repetitive code... Right !